# correct usage of erlang spawn_monitor

Tags: erlang

Still working through Joe's book, and having hard time fully understanding monitors in general and spawn_monitor in particular. Here's the code I have; the exercise is asking to write a function that will start a process whose job is to print a heartbeat every 5 seconds, and then a function to monitor the above process and restart it. I didn't get to a restart part, because my monitor fails to even detect the process keeling over.

```
% simple "working" loop
loop_5_print() ->
    receive
    after 5000 ->
            io:format("I'm still alive~n"),
            loop_5_print()
    end.

% function to spawn and register a named worker
create_reg_keep_alive(Name) when not is_atom(Name) ->
    {error, badargs};
create_reg_keep_alive(Name) ->
    Pid = spawn(ex, loop_5_print, []),
    register(Name, Pid),
    {Pid, Name}.

% a simple monitor loop
monitor_loop(AName) ->
    Pid = whereis(AName),
    io:format("monitoring PID ~p~n", [Pid]),
    receive
        {'DOWN', _Ref, process, Pid, Why} ->
            io:format("~p died because ~p~n",[AName, Why]),
            % add the restart logic
            monitor_loop(AName)
    end.

% function to bootstrapma monitor
my_monitor(AName) ->
    case whereis(AName) of
        undefined -> {error, no_such_registration};

        _Pid -> spawn_monitor(ex, monitor_loop, [AName])
    end.
```

And here's me playing with in:

```
39> c("ex.erl").                    
{ok,ex}
40> ex:create_reg_keep_alive(myjob).
{<0.147.0>,myjob}
I'm still alive                     
I'm still alive          
41> ex:my_monitor(myjob).
monitoring PID <0.147.0>
{<0.149.0>,#Ref<0.230612052.2032402433.56637>}
I'm still alive
I'm still alive                     
42> exit(whereis(myjob), stop).
true
43>
```

It sure stopped the *loop_5_print* "worker" - **but where's the line that the monitor was supposed to print?** The only explanation that I see is that the message emitted by a process quitting in this manner isn't of the pattern on which I am matching inside monitor loop's *receive*. But that's the only pattern introduced in the book in this chapter, so I'm not buying this explanation..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`spawn_monitor` is not what you want here. `spawn_monitor` spawns a process and immediately starts monitoring it. When the spawned process dies, the process that called `spawn_monitor` gets a message that the process is dead. You need to call `erlang:monitor/2` from the process that you want to receive the DOWN messages in, with the second argument being the Pid to monitor.

Just add:

```
monitor(process, Pid),
```

after:

```
Pid = whereis(AName),
```

and it works:

```
1> c(ex).
{ok,ex}
2> ex:create_reg_keep_alive(myjob).
{<0.67.0>,myjob}
I'm still alive
I'm still alive
I'm still alive
3> ex:my_monitor(myjob).
monitoring PID <0.67.0>
{<0.69.0>,#Ref<0.2696002348.2586050567.188678>}
I'm still alive
I'm still alive
I'm still alive
4> exit(whereis(myjob), stop).
myjob died because stop
true
monitoring PID undefined
```

Comment: my goodness, you're absolutely right. I keep getting confused with monitor semantics; and I've already realized at some point that spawn_monitor/3 doesn't mean "create a monitor", but rather, "create this computation, and monitor it" - yet I've reverted to my misunderstanding without realizing it.

Comment: thanks again mate - with your pointing out my error, I was able to fix, then refactor my solution; I feel the Erlang foo is getting stronger in me =)